# mistakes in a RiscV ISS implementation

Tags: riscv

I am developing a RiscV ISS and when I run the verification suite, I get an error with the add instruction. I nailed down the problem to this part of the code (register states during execution as comments):

```
lui   ra,0x80000   ;; ra = 0x80000000 
lui   sp,0xffff8   ;; sp = 0xffff8000
add   t5,ra,sp     ;; t5 = 0x17fff8000
lui   t4,0xffff0   ;; t4 = 0xffff0000
addiw t4,t4,-1     ;; t4 = 0xfffeffff
slli  t4,t4,0xf    ;; t4 = 0x7fff7fff8000
li    gp,7         ;; gp = 7
bne   t5,t4,800005f0 <fail> ;; The program branches to fail :(
```

Obviously registers t5 and t4 do not present the same values during execution and thus, the program branches to the fail routine.

Can anyone please point out which instruction(s) is/are generating bad results in my code?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the same program in spike to compare the results and found the bug. 
Both LUI and ADDIW instructions were missing the 32-bit sign extension. Thanks for the ones who read the post and put some thought.

Comment: Hello. What is the "ISS"? Is it public? Did you check riscvemu https://bellard.org/riscvemu/ by bellard and rv8 https://github.com/rv8-io/rv8 by michaeljclark?

Comment: Hi, it's an Instruction Set Simulator that I am building just for fun. Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This code is for an RV64I implementation (64 bits) I think.

The LUI instruction sign extends for RV64I implementations which you have not done on the first two lines.